# Brownian Motion Expectation-Like Integral

Tags: stochastic-processes

How much is

$$\int_0^T tB_t \, dt$$

where $B_t$ is Brownian motion and $T$ an universal constant?

Comment: yes, its independent of $t$ and $B_t$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a Gaussian variable with expectation zero and variance
$$
  \mathbb{E}\Bigl[\Bigl(\int_0^T tB_t\,dt\Bigr)^2\Bigr]
  =\int_0^T\int_0^T\mathbb{E}[stB_sB_t]\,ds\,dt
  =\int_0^T\int_0^Tst\min(s,t)\,ds\,dt.
$$
I expect you can compute the final integral yourself, by dividing the square into the two triangles given by $s<t$ and $s>t$.

Comment: I was going to write a more detailed, multiline calculation, but MathJax wouldn't cooperate – it refused to deal with the `aligned` environment for some odd reason. So I ran out of energy, sorry about that.

Comment: thanks! i can calculate the last integral myself. I understand you used Ito isometry

Comment: Not quite as fancy as that, since these are not Itō integrals. It's basically just Fubini's theorem, relying on the fact that the expectation is itself an integral. And then I use $\mathbb{E}[B_sB_t]=\min(s,t)$, which is a fundamental property of Brownian motion. In the first equality, I just write out the square as a product of the inner integral with itself, using different integration variables $s$ and $t$ in the two factors.

Comment: are you sure that the last step is valid? factoring the expectation where $t$ and $B_t$ have something in common?

Comment: As far as the expectation is concerned, $s$ and $t$ are just constants. And $\mathbb{E}[aX]=a\mathbb{E}[X]$ for deterministic $a$ and r.v. $X$.